# siunitx and amsmath incompatibility for listoffigures?

Tags: amsmath, siunitx, overleaf

I am writing a document (in Overleaf) that needs a list of figures, so I added `\listoffigures` right after the table of contents but I got a `Missing number, treated as zero` error. I believe that the problem is somehow related to the fact that I am using `\SI{number}{unit}` in a caption of a figure. However, for some reason if I remove the `amsmath` package everything works.

Here is a MWE which reproduces the issue

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} % <- Remove this and the error goes away
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Let's test it \SI{30}{\square\deg}}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried searching for similar questions, but none had a solution for my issue (as far as I have seen).

Do you have any idea how to tackle this problem?

Comment: with `\degree` instead of `\deg` it works (and I think that the unit name is `\degree`)

Comment: What is square degree?

Comment: I suggest you replace `\SI{30}{\square\deg}` with `\SI{30}{\deg\squared}`. (`\deg` is supposed to output "deg", right?)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I assumed `\deg` was part of `siunitx` and I used it because I needed to have `deg`^2 instead of '°'^2. @Rmano, thanks, but I have to use `deg`. @daleif A measure of solid angle, but [Wikipedia explains better than me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_degree). @Mico I will try it and yes, I need `deg`!

Comment: @Mico what you suggested works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

The command `\deg` is not one of the unit names accepted by `siunitx`, but an operator name like `\log`.

You can define your own unit or override the standard output for `\degree`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\degree}{deg}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \fbox{figure}
    \caption{Let's test it \SI{30}{\square\degree} or \SI{30}{\degree\squared}}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg, I really though `\deg` was part of `siunitx`. I unfortunately cannot override the unit as I need the `°` in some other places, but knowing that I could be able to do it is a nice thing to learn anyway. I will probably define a new unit  anyway, that seems easier!

Comment: In the end, I think I will used the `\SI{30}{\deg\squared}` notation!

Comment: @Ale Don't, unless you also do `\DeclareSIUnit{\deg}{deg}`

Comment: Oh wait why? Apparently it is working, what is happening that might cause problems? Anyway that is something I can definitely do because I only use `\deg` as unit.